# Can't see Sinhala Unicode characters in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, unicode, utf-8

I tried to print Sinhala characters in **NetBeans 7.1** Java application.(In windows 7)
Other languages like Chinese and Urdu .. etc will show the correct character. But Sinhala characters are not displaying correctly. **It will  display as little boxes** both in the code and the output. though here in SO it show as "සිංහල" . How can I fix it ?

**I can do this without a problem in eclipse environment.**

```
    String a = "世界你好";
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println("कई");

    // sinhala
    char c = '\u0D85';
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println("\u0D85");
    System.out.println("සිංහල");

    System.out.println(java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset().name());
```

I tried changing the Sources -> Encoding type to UTF-8.
and now my netbeans.conf file I changed **netbeans_default_options** and added **-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8**  like below

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -J-Dorg.netbeans.modules.tomcat.autoregister.token=1378930362898 -J-Dorg.netbeans.modules.tomcat.autoregister.catalinaHome=\"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.20\" -J-Dorg.glassfish.v3ee6.installRoot=\"C:\Program Files\sges-v3\" -J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

How can I fix this. ?

Comment: [this](http://ditoinfo.wordpress.com/2007/02/26/netbeans-and-utf8-encoding-2/) site has a way and i tried it also. but didn't work.

Comment: Check the **font**: menu Tools / Options / Fonts & Colors (in NetBeans 8). In the project properties check that UTF-8 is used. It is probably a limited font, Monospaced.

Comment: for what exactly i check in Tools / Options / Fonts & Colors .. I already  set project properties ->  UTF-8  .

Comment: I suspect thet the IDE's font might be missing character glyphs for Sinhala ones. Something which can be easily checked. UTF-8 is just a confirmation that everything is as it should.

Comment: So how can I fix that. You said it can be easily checked. how can I check that ?

Comment: If the font is say "Monospaced" you can try out that font, in CharMap, Word or whatever. And you can select another font.

Answer (score 6):

The default **monospaced** font in Netbeans is not sufficient for unicode characters. Try using a unicode font that supports Sinhala. Windows 8 comes with **Iskoola Pota** and [Nirmala UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirmala_UI) which can display Sinhala nicely. I don't know if you can find these two fonts on Windows 7, but you can download [GNU FreeFont](http://www.gnu.org/software/freefont/) (*only* **FreeSerif** has Sinhala) as an alternative to **Iskoola Pota** or **Nirmala UI**.

To see Sinhala characters in the **editor display**, select Netbeans menu: Tools => Options ==> Fonts & Colors => Syntax Tab => Category Default => Font and set it to either **Iskoola Pota** or **Nirmala UI** or **FreeSerif**.

Likewise, to see Sinhala characters in the **output display**, select Netbeans menu: Tools ==> Options ==> Miscellaneous ==> Output tab ==> Font and set it to either **Iskoola Pota** or **Nirmala UI** or **FreeSerif**. You can right click on the output display and choose **Settings...** to go there directly.

This is your code and output in Netbeans 8.0.2 on Windows 8 with **FreeSerif** font.

[image]

More reading on Sinhala fonts: [Unicode Font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font) and [List of typefaces included with Microsoft Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows)

Answer (score 0):

For each textbox or edittext set font into iscolapota.

Comment: will be good if you could add a snippet of your code solution to help OP